# Binary Search Tree StudentDatabase

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

Consider that I have a generic binary search tree. I have students' class and I keep the student's id as a key in bst. Then I want to search these students according to their name and I want to delete one of them. But I keep students according to their id's. How can I search them according to their name? Please give me the information. (Java language)

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your goal? Why do want to keep id as the key in your BST?

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 BSTs, key of one is id and for another is name. So you can access an element by their name or id both in O(log n) time.

This will double the memory and time requirements for your data structure. (Only insertions and deletions will take double time. The other operations will take no extra time). However, recall that O(2 log n) is generally treated the same as O(log n).

You cannot do better than this using BSTs. Since you need to search based on name in O(log n) time, name must be the key for the tree. However, you also need to retrieve the users by id therefore, id must also be a key for the tree. Hence, you need two trees.

Comment: I want to get an answer as java and please write some code :) i make some searching if i use hash map it will be okey but i don't know how can i do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your BST contains student objects as a node with left and right pointers. You can implement search method as shown below:

```
    public Student search(Student root, String key)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Student result1 = search(root.left, key);

        if(result1 != null)
        {
            return result1;
        }

        if(key.equals(root.studentName))
        {
            return root;
        }

        Student result2 = search(root.right, key);

        if(result2 != null)
        {
            return result2;
        }

        return null;
    }
```